# Как закрывать окна при переходе между страницами в next.js?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, nextjs, spa, next.js

В проекте на next.js шапка и подвал на всех страницах одинаковые и помещены в _app.tsx в виде компонента Layout, который в качестве ребёнка принимает Component страницы. Т.е. при переходе по страницам шапка и подвал не меняются. Это очень удобно. Но возникла проблема.

Если в шапке открыть например popup, то при переходе на следующую страницу он по логике должне закрыться, но он не закроется т.к. это SPA шапка и подвал заданы единой обёрткой для страниц и не перерисовываютя при переходе между страницами.

Подскажите есть ли в next.js какие нибудь готовые решения для данной проблемы?

Можно ли как то может вручную добавить обработчик на переход между страницами и в нём в шапке и подвале закрывать открывшиеся из них окна и выпадающие меню?

Comment: При переходе на другую страницу после клика по ссылке в popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть. Через состояние попапа т.е. через useState.

например у меня открывается меню и если нажать на любую страницу меню будет открыто. решил это так:

```
const [isNavCollapsed, setIsNavCollapsed] = useState(true);
const handleNavClose = () => setIsNavCollapsed(true);
const handleNavCollapse = () => setIsNavCollapsed(!isNavCollapsed);
```

Вызов меню осуществляется

```
onClick={ handleNavCollapse }
```

и повесил на блок для закрытия при переходе:

```
onClick={ handleNavClose }
```

Данный пример Вам не подойдет т.к. нет конкретного примера, но думаю направление будет понятно

Также есть через _app / useEffect и useRouter

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
        console.log(`URL изменен на ${url}`)
/* ДОБАВИТЬ СЮДА ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ СОСТОЯНИЯ ПОПАПА НА ДЕФОЛТНОЕ */
    }
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
    }
}, [])
```